# JavaScript Importando Classes

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JavaScript a uns dias e tenho sentido algumas dificuldades em aplicar POO nesta linguagem. Minha duvida é referente a importação de classes para usar o seus métodos.

```
class Pessoa(){
constructor(nome,idade){
  this.nome = nome
  this.idade = idade
}
 falar(){
console.log("Nome:" + this.nome + " Idade: " + this.idade)
      }
}
```

Tenho essa classe e gostaria de usar ela em um outro arquivo, importando ela e executando algo como:

```
const pessoa1 = new Pessoa("João",12)
pessoa1.falar()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se utilizar o [commonjs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules), uma maneira de resolver o problema é o seguinte:

criar um arquivo `pessoa.js`, ao final do arquivo, você deve exportar a classe:

```
class Pessoa {
    constructor(nome, idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    falar() {
      console.log("Nome:" + this.nome + " Idade: " + this.idade);
    }
}

module.exports = Pessoa
```

Depois no arquivo `app.js`, você deve importar a classe exportada, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
const Pessoa = require('./pessoa');

const pessoa1 = new Pessoa("João", 12);
pessoa1.falar();
```

Depois, para verificar o funcionamento basta executar o comando:

```
node app.js
```

O resultado esperado para esta execução é o seguinte:

```
node app.js
Nome:João Idade: 12
```

A organização de diretório para este projeto é o seguinte:

```
.
├── pessoa.js
└── app.js
```

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: Cara isso resolveu demais meu problema !! Era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando brigadão... Toda vez que eu pergunto algo o pessoa já vem logo com biblioteca framework e um monte de coisa, mas eu estou estudando o java script puro ainda kkkk.

Answer (score -2):

Para importar a classe `Pessoa` em outro arquivo JavaScript, você pode usar a palavra-chave `import`. Primeiro, você precisa exportar a classe do arquivo onde ela está definida, adicionando a palavra-chave `export` antes da definição da classe:

```
export class Pessoa {
  constructor(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }

  falar() {
    console.log("Nome:" + this.nome + " Idade: " + this.idade);
  }
}
```

Em seguida, você pode importar a classe em outro arquivo usando a palavra-chave `import` e especificando o caminho para o arquivo onde a classe está definida:

```
import { Pessoa } from './caminho/para/arquivo';

const pessoa1 = new Pessoa("João", 12);
pessoa1.falar();
```

Observe que você pode importar várias classes de um único arquivo, separando-as por vírgula. Você também pode usar o `import * as` para importar todas as classes de um arquivo em um único objeto.

```
import * as classes from './caminho/para/arquivo';

const pessoa1 = new classes.Pessoa("João", 12);
pessoa1.falar();
```

Comment: Ele retorna esse erro: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Uma solução simples é criar (caso não tenha) um arquivo `package.json` no diretório raiz do seu projeto e adicionar `"type": "module"` nele.

Comment: se estiver usando js junto com html use <script type='module' src='path/to/file.js'>//Code</script>